# Sqlite2 graphical tool

Tags: sqlite

I have a (non-trivial) sqlite2 database that I would like to view graphically through a tool similar to the SQLite manager for Firefox or PHPMyAdmin for MySQL.

Problem is everything I find is (understandably) for SQLite 3. Does anyone know of such a freeware tool for SQLite 2?

Comment: btw I wanted to tag this sqlite2 but don't have the reputation to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) work?

[image: screenshot table definition]
[image: screenshot table diagram]

Wikipedia's [comparison of SQL tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools) has a column for SQLite. 
It doesn't specify version but it might make a useful shortlist to check.

A [2007 blog article](http://www.geekfarm.org/wu/muse/SQLite.html) mentions SQLite (unspecified version but presumably 2007 vintage) and SQuirreL and JDBC.

Comment: It doesn't explicitely list support but I'll try to get it to work with a sqlite2 JBDC driver